# Map many:optional relationships from multiple entity types EF CodeFirst

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, fluent-interface

We have 3 entities that relate to each other as such:

- Foo has many Attachments
- Bar has many Attachments
- Each Attachment can belong to either of Foo or Bar.

What is the best way to model this using `DbModelBuilder`?

If we try:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>().HasMany(t => t.Attachments).WithOptional()
    .Map(m => m.MapKey("FOO_ID")).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
modelBuilder.Entity<Bar>().HasMany(t => t.Attachments).WithOptional()
    .Map(m => m.MapKey("BAR_ID")).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

This is not a very clean data model:
* The Attachments table will have two FK columns, one for each possible parent entities ('FOO_ID', 'BAR_ID'). If we increase the number of entities that need attachments, it bloats the table.
* We need to make the backward reference optional although of course an attachment is always attached to an entity. It just needn't necessarily be a Foo, and it needn't be a Bar. But an attachment with all FK's set to NULL will be allowed by the schema although it is not valid from a business view.
* In theory one Attachment could be linked to both a Foo and a Bar, which is not valid.

Instead we might map the relationships to junction tables 'T_FOO_ATTACHMENT' and 'T_BAR_ATTACHMENT':
* T_FOO_ATTACHMENT has a *required* foreign key to Foo (FOO_ID) and a required FK to Attachment (ATTACHMENT_ID).
* The same holds for T_BAR_ATTACHMENT

Downsides:
* An attachment could still be linked to a Foo and a Bar.
* An attachment could even be linked to multiple Foo's, which is not valid either. Ideally we could use the fluent syntax to add DB constraints that prevent that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is not a very clean data model: The Attachments table will have
>   two FK columns, one for each possible parent entities ('FOO_ID',
>   'BAR_ID').

But it is absolutely correct from relational perspective - if you want to have relation with another table you need a new foreign key.

> But an attachment with all FK's set to NULL will be allowed by the
>   schema although it is not valid from a business view. In theory one
>   Attachment could be linked to both a Foo and a Bar, which is not
>   valid.

That is your business logic. With your current model you must enforce it in your application.

What you are looking for is some kind of named relations where the `Attachment` doesn't have only FK but also the name of related table. That is something you will not achieve on relational level - it is data level (again business logic) and it cannot be mapped with EF.

Comment: Thanks Ladislav. There's always good hope if your name appears in the answers :-) - For the named relations: I would stay away from those, too. My OOP thinking tells me to avoid circular references, therefore I'm trying to not have any FK's in the Attachment at all but use junction tables instead. But that may be overengineered.

Comment: ... and yes, in fact the business logic is already covered by the code. The only way for a user to add attachments will always be inline with the business rules.